# Unload event handler fakeLoader.js so that it loads on every button click

Tags: jquery, css, fakeloader.js

Is there a way of having the fake loader reload on every button click without it waiting for page reload

```
     <div id="fakeLoader"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#fakeloader").fakeLoader({   timeToHide:1200, //Time in milliseconds for fakeLoader disappear
       zIndex:"999",//Default zIndex 
        spinner:"spinner1",//Options: 'spinner1', 'spinner2', 'spinner3', 'spinner4', 'spinner5', 'spinner6', 'spinner7'
        bgColor:"#2ecc71", //Hex, RGB or RGBA colors
        imagePath:"yourPath/customizedImage.gif" //If you want can you insert your custom image

      });

   </script>
```

Comment: http://joaopereirawd.github.io/fakeLoader.js/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to unload it as such. It does that by itself after `timeToHide` ms has passed.

You can also bind events to trigger the fakeLoader.
The example below will trigger the fakeLoader on every single click on an `<a...>` link, but you can bind it to any event:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
      $("#fakeloader").fakeLoader({   timeToHide:1200, //Time in milliseconds for fakeLoader disappear
       zIndex:"999",//Default zIndex 
        spinner:"spinner1",//Options: 'spinner1', 'spinner2', 'spinner3', 'spinner4', 'spinner5', 'spinner6', 'spinner7'
        bgColor:"#2ecc71", //Hex, RGB or RGBA colors
        imagePath:"yourPath/customizedImage.gif" //If you want can you insert your custom image

      });
});
```